# error inflating to next activity

Tags: android

this is my error

```
method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
```

this is my code

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapse_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:background="@drawable/gmdw"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">


            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:titleMarginTop="15dp" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="62dp"
                android:layout_gravity="clip_vertical|bottom"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>



    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Do you have Floating action button in your hierarchy?

Comment: post your java file ..

Comment: the error was because of multiple threads in an activity. I solved that error removing drawer